# PHP-MySQL connection error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL via PHP through the following code

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$pass   = 'pass';


 $con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$pass);
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("test", $con);

 mysql_query("UPDATE cbdb SET fax = '36160'
 WHERE cemail = 'test_cemail@gmail.com' AND cbref = 'test_cbref'");

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

but an error is showing even though the MySQL connection error is displayed.

Comment: Just a tip, you may want to set error_reporting(E_ALL); in the beginning of your php script. This way you'll be notified of all errors. Right now it looks like you're suppressing some errors.

Comment: I found this post from [the effort to close typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions#comment498341_168974).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing ; after pass and use following syntax

```
   $db_host=" "; //the host name of the sql server (if you do not know, leave as localhost. usually works)
   $db_name=" ";  //the name of the database
   $db_user=" ";  //the username that is associated with the database
   $db_pass=" "; //the password for the username

   $dbc=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());
   $dbs=mysql_select_db($db_name) OR DIE (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 5):

are you missing a semi colon after 'pass' ?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon on the `$pass` line.